# Python, Search Event Descriptions on Google Calendar

Tags: python, google-calendar-api

I have the Python [example script](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/quickstart/python) Google provides working, but I can not figure out how to return only results with certain words in the description of the event.  For instance, I would like to be able to return a list of events with the word "Baltimore" in the description. Can anyone provide an example or point me to some documentation?

Answer (score 0):

without any kind of example output I would think you would want to search the returned string against a substring

```
string = " i live in Baltimore"
subString = "Baltimore"
print subString in string
```

this returns true

Comment: That's right Alec, I just don't know how to inject that string in way that the API can use it in the query.  I imagine it should go somewhere in here:  'eventsResult = service.events().list(
        calendarId='primary', timeMin=now, maxResults=10, singleEvents=True,
        orderBy='startTime').execute()
    events = eventsResult.get('items', [])

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, pretty simple:

```
while True:
  events = service.events().list(calendarId='primary', q='Baltimore', pageToken=page_token).execute()
  for event in events['items']:
    print event['summary']
  page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
  if not page_token:
    break
```